# Is there a faster way to connect to a Bluetooth device from cmd/powershell than btcom from Bluetooth command line tools?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, bluetooth

I've put together a Powershell script to allow me to connect my Bluetooth headphones to my PC without having to open the Bluetooth settings page each time (based on the ones in https://github.com/stanleyguevara/win10-bluetooth-headphones, but using `Get-PnPDevice` and `Get-PnPDeviceProperty` to check whether the device is connected rather than using an environment variable to save the state).

The script works, but there's one big QoL issue. The script uses the Bluetooth command line tools [here](https://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools) to connect/disconnect the device (in particular, it uses the `btcom` command). However, these commands are very slow to run, with the whole process taking around a minute total. This is true even though I am using the device's MAC address to connect, and not its friendly name (which would be even slower). This makes using the script much slower than just opening the settings panel each time (though opening the settings panel is less convenient since it requires opening and going through multiple windows).

I've seen many questions about this sort of thing (how to connect/disconnect a Bluetooth device from cmd/powershell, but everything I've seen regarding Windows tends to suggest using the Bluetooth command line tools at the link above, so they don't solve the speed issue. Other things I've found suggest disabling the Bluetooth adapter entirely, which isn't what I want to do. Others suggest using the Win+K shortcut to open up the connections sidepanel, but this doesn't really address the question of whether there's a way to do this from cmd/powershell, and is slightly less automated since you have to wait a second for the list to populate and manually navigate to the device to connect/disconnect (though at least it solves the problem of opening a bunch of windows).

Is there a way to connect/disconnect from a Bluetooth device in cmd/powershell that is faster than `btcom`?

Comment: The only way to speed up this is to do not uninstall device's services when disconnectiong. Instead use "disconnect" command. This takes time to connect first time. But next time the services will already be installed so connection will be faster. Unofrtunatley you have to write your own command line tool to do that because I do not know any one already written.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is my solution to turn bluetooth on/off using cmd:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "bluetoothStatus="
set "command="

:: Check current Bluetooth status
for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %%a in ('reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BTHPORT\Parameters\Radio Management" /v "Enable" ^| find "Enable"') do (
    set "bluetoothStatus=%%a"
)

if /i "%bluetoothStatus%"=="0x1" (
    set "command=stop"
) else (
    set "command=start"
)

:: Execute the command
if /i "%command%"=="start" (
    echo Turning on Bluetooth...
    net start bthserv
) else (
    echo Turning off Bluetooth...
    net stop bthserv
)

:: Display the updated Bluetooth status
for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %%a in ('reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BTHPORT\Parameters\Radio Management" /v "Enable" ^| find "Enable"') do (
    set "bluetoothStatus=%%a"
)

if /i "%bluetoothStatus%"=="0x1" (
    echo Bluetooth is now ON.
) else (
    echo Bluetooth is now OFF.
)

endlocal
```

Save the above code in a file with a .bat extension, such as laosBlue.bat. To use it, double-click on the batch file, and it will toggle the Bluetooth status between on and off.

Comment: Please note that modifying the registry and stopping services may require administrative privileges. Make sure to run the batch file as an administrator if needed.

Remember that working with the registry and services can have consequences, so use this script at your own risk.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this turns on/off bluetooth services completely (i.e., for the whole computer). I don't necessarily want to do that—I just want to connect/disconnect a single device, without connecting/disconnecting _everything_. Still useful to know, just not quite what I'm looking for if I understand it correctly.